# how to pass a variable to graphql query?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I have a question.
There is a function that returns the result of a graphql query. In this function, I want to pass the arguments that will be used in the request, for example, to control order direction.
How can i do this?

1) Fucntion query

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export const useSiteMetadata = (dir) => {

  const {allContentfulBlogPost:{edges}} = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
        query {
            allContentfulBlogPost(
                sort:{
                    fields: published,
                    order: $dir

                }
            ){
                edges{
                    node{
                        name,                        
                        alias,
                        published,
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `
  );
  return edges;
};
```

2)Function call

```
const res = useSiteMetadata('ASC');
```

[exempel code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5HZS.png.)

Comment: Hello, according to gatsby's doc : `StaticQuery does not accept variables (hence the name “static”), but can be used in any component, including pages` https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/

Comment: @Hssen Thanks for the answer. I saw this solution. I hoped that I could do it through useStaticQuery. thank

Comment: `useStaticQuery ` and `StaticQuery` practically serve the same purpose and share the same limitation - there is no way to use variables with either of them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export const useSiteMetadata = (dir) => {
  const { allPostsAsc, allPostsDsc } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allPostsAsc: allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: published, order: "ASC" }) {
          edges {
            node {
              name
              alias
              published
              id
            }
          }
        }
        allPostsDsc: allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: published, order: "DSC" }) {
          edges {
            node {
              name
              alias
              published
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
  const posts = {
    ASC: allPostsAsc,
    DSC: allPostsDsc
  }

  return posts[dir]
};
```